# Which run-time memory checkers have been known to work with Sophis Risque 6.x

Tags: c++, debugging, crash

For debugging sporadic crashes in Sophis Risque, we need to be able to run Sophis with our C++ plugins in a run-time code analysis tool such as BoundsChecker or Purify. I have successfully used both of these tools Risque 4.x versions, but none of them works anymore since Risque 5.3.x. Even without our plugins, neither the Sophis Client, nor any Toolkit API applications ever manage to successfully initialize the session - the process will crash before the Toolkit Log is created. I have the impression that Risque stopped working with Purify somewhere between risque 4.5 and 5.2, and with BoundsChecker between risque 5.2 and 5.3. Under Risque 5.3, I've tried upgrading BoundsChecker from 9.01 to 10.5.897.1, but the same problem occurred: during the call to CSRApi::Initialise() an "Unhandled exception" was detected and the process couldn't continue. Meanwhile we use Risque 6.3.x and need some serious tools for debugging.

Question: Which run-time memory checking tools (and which versions thereof) have been ever known to work with Sophis Risque 6.x ? Are we really limited to the Basic Runtime Checks available for debug builds in Visual Studio via C++ project properties->Code Generation->Basic Runtime Checks (/RTCs /RTCu /RTCsu)? Thanks!